# Sending data from activity to foreground service

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I am receiving data from a microcontroller via Bluetooth in an activity. This data is continuously sent to the app and I am using a foreground service to implement this thread in the background.

Data is received in MainActivity4, the an intent is sent to a foreground service class with the data received which then redirects the data to MainActivity5 where it will be graphed.

I am not sure how to implement the intent properly that is sent to the MainActivity4 because the data is continuously being processed by the foreground service but is not redirecting it constantly to MainActivity5. The first time the intent makes the screen go to the MainActivity5 which is good but the data is not being sent and updated.

Here is the code in MainActivity4:

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);

        String value = String.valueOf(characteristic.getValue());
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity4.this, ForegroundService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", value);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(MainActivity4.this, serviceIntent);
}
```

Here is the code in the ForegroundService:

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {

//private static final int ID_SERVICE = 101;
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
    Log.i("Tag", input);
    sendData(input);

    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
    //do heavy work on a background thread
    //stopSelf();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
    //return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
        return null;
}

private void sendData(String input){
    Log.i("Tag", "inside sendData");
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(ForegroundService.this, MainActivity5.class);
    intent2.putExtra("inputExtra", input);
    intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    //intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    //intent2.putExtra("inputExtra", input);
    startActivity(intent2);
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Foreground Service Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code in the MainActivity5:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String data = intent.getStringExtra("inputString");
    Log.i(TAG, "data sending");
    dataText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data2);
    dataText.setText(data);
```

How am I able to receive the data in the MainActivity5 continuously? Perhaps the Intent set flags is what I am getting wrong. The data is received in the background and is sent to the foreground service but not to the other activity despite that activity's screen is automatically opened when the code is run. Any help and advice would be appreciated. Thanks

*** Here is an update to what I have so far a function in Foreground Service class:

```
private void sendData(String input){
    Log.i("Tag", "inside sendData");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.example.Pillwoah.sendbroadcast");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    intent.putExtra("inputExtra", input);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

*** Here is an update to what I have so far a function in MainActivity5:

```
public class MainActivity5 extends AppCompatActivity {

protected static final String TAG = "TAG";

TextView dataText;

BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

    GraphView move = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.move);
    GraphView sound = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.sound);

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 1),
            new DataPoint(1, 5),
            new DataPoint(2, 3),
            new DataPoint(3, 2),
            new DataPoint(4, 6)
    });
    move.addSeries(series);
    series.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    series.setDrawDataPoints(true);
    series.setAnimated(true);
    series.setDrawBackground(true);

    move.setTitle("Movement");
    move.setTitleTextSize(90);
    move.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series2 = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 1),
            new DataPoint(1, 5),
            new DataPoint(2, 4),
            new DataPoint(3, 9),
            new DataPoint(4, 6)
    });
    sound.addSeries(series);
    series2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    series2.setDrawDataPoints(true);
    series2.setAnimated(true);
    series2.setDrawBackground(true);

    sound.setTitle("Sound");
    sound.setTitleTextSize(90);
    sound.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);

    Log.i(TAG, "data sending");
    configureReceiver();
}
class DataBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = "Broadcast intent detected " + intent.getAction();
        Log.i(TAG, message);
    }
}

private void configureReceiver(){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.example.Pillwoah.sendbroadcast");
    receiver = new DataBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

}
```

I am getting no errors but I know that I am missing some bit of functionality. If anyone could see what I am missing that would be great.

Comment: You can use a broadcast receiver to send data from service to MainActivity4

Comment: Thanks @guest How would I be able to implement this? Do I need a broadcast receiver class or can that be a function inside MainActivity4?

Answer (score 2):

There is a sample with broadcast receiver

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    companion object {
        const val ACTION_DATA = "package.your.app.DATA"
        private val filters = arrayOf(ACTION_DATA)
        private val intentFilter: IntentFilter by lazy {
            IntentFilter().apply {
                filters.forEach { addAction(it) }
            }
        }

    }
    inner class DataBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            when (intent.action) {
                ACTION_DATA -> showData(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    fun showData(intent: Intent) {
        //TODO extract data from intent
    }

    private lateinit var broadcastReceiver: MainActivity.DataBroadcastReceiver

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        broadcastReceiver = DataBroadcastReceiver()
        applicationContext.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)
    }
}

class ForegroundService: Service() {
    ...
    private fun sendData(input: String) {
        Intent().run {
            action = MainActivity.ACTION_DATA
            putExtra("inputExtra", input)
            applicationContext.sendBroadcast(this)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That code above is in Kotlin, right? I tried implementing some of it in java for my code but I ran into a couple errors

Comment: I have edited the post with what I put into the service class

Comment: I am still having a hard time to understand how the code would be understood in java

Comment: @RomkoSmuk Sorry. The Kotlin programming language is now its preferred language for Android app developers. What part of the sample should be explained?

Comment: I believe I was able to figure it out. Basically it was the private lateinit  line, inside function onReceive and inside companion object